# Issue with rewriting an Access Query in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am currently trying to replicate an MS Access query in SQL server and I have some issues going on with this query.

I am running getting too many records in SQL server with my new query.
Original MS Access query - produces 64632 records

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Deb D INNER JOIN Bals B ON D.ID = B.ID
WHERE 
(
    D.ID > 9999999
    AND (B.TYPE <> 'DV' Or B.TYPE Is Null)
    AND (D.SEC < 9999800 And D.SEC <> 9999000 And D.SEC <>9999100)
    AND (B.BR<>'C2' Or B.BR<>'TA')
)
OR
(
    D.ID > 9999999
    AND (B.TYPE <> 'DV' Or B.TYPE Is Null)
    AND (D.SEC < 9999800 And D.SEC <> 9999000 And D.SEC <>9999100)
    AND B.BR Is Null
)
```

New SQL version produces 64658 records

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Deb D INNER JOIN Bals B ON D.ID = B.ID
WHERE 
    D.ID > 9999999
    AND (B.TYPE <> 'DV' Or B.TYPE Is Null)
    AND (D.SEC < 9999800 And D.SEC <> 9999000 And D.SEC <>9999100)
    AND (
            (B.BR<>'C2' Or B.BR<>'TA')
            Or
            (B.BR Is Null)

        )
```

As you can see I combined the items from the 2 original `OR` statements in the `WHERE` clause because the only difference was this

```
(B.BR<>'C2' Or B.BR<>'TA')
Or
(B.BR Is Null)
```

I know the problem is coming from `B.BR<>'C2' Or B.BR<>'TA'` in SQL server. It is still including the items with the 'C2' and 'TA' values even though they should be excluded.  I cannot figure out how to correct this.  Suggestions?

Comment: try `B.BR<>'C2' AND B.BR<>'TA'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to determine which extra rows you are getting, but I suspect they are rows where B.BR is either 'C2' or 'TA'. Since the following cannot eliminate both values at the same time:

```
B.BR <> 'C2' OR B.BR <> 'TA'
```

Try the following instead:

```
B.BR NOT IN ('C2', 'TA')
```

Comment: That seemed to work.  Do you think I will wind up with the same type of issue with this part of the query:  

(B.ACCT_TYPE_IND <> 'DV' Or B.ACCT_TYPE_IND Is Null)

Comment: I don't think so, the IS NULL condition is a different type of check than two exact value comparisons. Try this: DECLARE @x TABLE(a VARCHAR(4));
INSERT @x SELECT 'BV' UNION SELECT 'DV' UNION SELECT NULL;
SELECT a FROM @x WHERE a <> 'DV' OR a IS NULL;